# Regular expression: a string (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, can include '\', '/' and white sapce)

Tags: jquery, regex

I want a regex that has a string  `(a-z, A-Z, 0-9, can include '\', '/' and white sapces)`

I tried it like this:

```
if (/[\s\\\/A-Za-z0-9]$/.test(Yourval)),
```

but it doesn't work well, can somebody help me? thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example script including strings you've tested this on?

Comment: What does "doesn't work well" mean? You seem to be forgetting to  allow more than one character in the match.

Comment: you are only testing whether the last character is in this class. try replacing the `$` by `*$` and add a `^` to the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\\\/]+$/.test('Something with / and \\ 0 9')) { 
  alert('Good news everyone!'); 
}
```

... as you need two anchors here (both for the start and the end of the string), and `+` quantifier to test for more than a single character. In fact, this can be rewritten just as...

```
if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\\\/]/.test('Something with / and \\ 0 9')) { 
  alert('Crazy gibberish!'); 
}
```

... so we test for bad characters instead of trying to cover the string with only good ones. )

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following regex:

```
/^[\s\\\/A-Za-z0-9]+$/.test(Yourval)
```

or you can test for the existence of a bad character like this:

```
/[^\s\\\/A-Za-z0-9]/.test(Yourval)
```

Comment: He _should_ be searching for start and end of string, though. Otherwise that means it only has to contain *one* of those characters. He just needs to search for multiple in the string.